# how to fix unsafe precondition(s) violated: ptr::read requires that the pointer argument is aligned and non-null assert

Tags: rust, memory, riscv

hitting following assert

```bash
unsafe precondition(s) violated: ptr::read requires that the pointer argument is aligned and non-null
```

when running following small rust program with opt-level=0 on my custom target for rust.
The custom target is based on riscv32im.

```rust
#![cfg_attr(target_os = "zkvm", no_main)]
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

//extern crate alloc;

use rkyv::{Archive, Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Archive, Deserialize, Serialize, Debug, PartialEq)]
#[archive(
    // This will generate a PartialEq impl between our unarchived and archived
    // types:
    compare(PartialEq),
)]
// Derives can be passed through to the generated type:
#[archive_attr(derive(Debug))]
pub struct Test {
    pub int: u8,
}

pub fn main() {
    let value = Test {
        int: 42,
    };

   //Serializing is as easy as a single function call
   let bytes = rkyv::to_bytes::<_, 256>(&value).unwrap();

    core::hint::black_box(bytes);
}

guest::entry!(main);
```

Can someone please help me understand what's going wrong? This works fine on other similar arch (even with opt-level=0)?

Comment: It's a wild guess but it could be that the library `rkyv` makes assumptions about the memory alignment that are usually true, but not on niche architectures like the one you're trying to target?

Comment: You should file this as an issue with the rkyv library

Comment: The assertion failure was because of start of stack address was not aligned to power of 2. After changing the value to be aligned to 2 it works fine now.